# How to check whether feasible solutions for linear programs do exist?

Tags: linear-programming, decision-problems

For a linear program, how to decide whether there exists a feasible solution without solving it?

For $Ax \le b$, is there any sufficient and/or necessary condition represented by matrix $A$ and vector $b$ to decide the existence of a feasible solution without solving the problem?

Comment: please state the complete feasible set. If it is $\{x|Ax\le B\}$ and $B\ge 0$, then $x=0$ is feasible.

Comment: This is just a special case, I need a general answer. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Do you need a constructive method?

Comment: what do you mean by constructive method? I want a method which can easily be implemented on computer, I don't really care about the theory behind.

Comment: That's what I meant. then, in general, you need to implement the simplex method or something similar.

Comment: There is no method that is cheaper than solving the original problem. Look at "two-phase" methods for linear programming; you are looking for phase I. But in fact, you don't *need* to use two-phase methods; there are methods that determine feasibility and optimality in a single phase, and those are just as cheap (theoretically).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out whether linear programming problem is infeasible using simplex algorithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314137/how-to-find-out-whether-linear-programming-problem-is-infeasible-using-simplex-a)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following result:

**Theorem** (Farkas lemma, 1894):
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Then $Ax\le b$ has a solution if and only if $A^Ty=0$, $y\ge 0$, $b^Ty<0$ has no solution.

**Corollary**: In other words, $A^Ty=0$, $y\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $b^Ty\ge 0$.

Comment: thanks, I will have a try.